# How to create a public synynom in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There is a schema say 'A' in which there is a package called 'B' in which this is a function (below). In this function '**TIMESTMAP'** is used which while compiling in 11g is giving error. I want to create a public synonym for TIMESTAMP. Can anyone please provide me the script for the same.

```
FUNCTION generate_random_number
Return Number
IS
l_seq_no   VARCHA2(6)
l_sys_date   CHAR(10)
BEGIN
SELECT LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP.NEXTVAL,'000000'), ' ')
INTO l_seq_no
from DUAL;

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'H24:MI:SS')
INTO l_sys_date 
from DUAL
```

Comment: What have you tried? what error msg did you get? here is how to create synonyms http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7001.htm

Comment: forget the error and I have already this document. I am not able to make it. Can you please sugest

Comment: Are you sure that the sequence exists? do you have privileges for it? you did try to create the public synonym as the owner of this sequence, right ?

Comment: BTW, why do you need a `public synonym`? why not a regular one?

Comment: "forget the error".  Fnord.  It's all about the error.  If you have read the documentation and correctly followed the syntax then we need to know the error message that's preventing you from creating the public synonym.  Of course you don't have to give us any additional information, it just depnds on how much you actually want an answer to your question.

Comment: Anyway, why not use the Oracle built-in DBMS_RANDOM which, while not perfectly random, is likely to be  alot more random than your handrolled code?  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#sthref4646

Answer (score 2):

TIMESTAMP is a reserved word so it will be interpreting your code as TIMESTAMP being a datatype (so I guess the error your getting is nextval must be declared or something). So whilst you can create a sequence called TIMESTAMP, it is extremely silly to do so. you should rename the synonym. Failing that you can create a synonym (public or private) with a different name.

eg:

```
SQL> create sequence timestamp start with 1;

Sequence created.

SQL>
```

This sequence can be used in SQL but it cannot be used in PL/SQL (which is what the OP is trying to do).  The function won't compile (with a PL-00302 error).  So we must create a synonym for it:

```
SQL> create synonym t for timestamp;

Synonym created.
```

then use `T` in your code.

your code also has numerous other typos. missing `;` and mistyped `varchar2`. Finally `char(10)` for the time will mean its blank padded with 2 trailing spaces (as the length of the string will be 8 chars).

Comment: Actually Oracle does know that TIMESTAMP is a sequence, and will permit its use.  It's like a lot of the more recently introduced keywords (TYPE is another) Oracle can't actually ban their use as identifieres without breaking a huge swathe of the existing codebase.

Comment: @APC but if you try and use it in plsql it will complain about it. in sql it works.. that's the point iI was trying to make.

Comment: Er, so why not make that point in your answer?